# Проблемы при написании бота телеграм

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Написал в отдельный файл код, но не знаю как его импортировать в основной код.

**Код фильтра слов:**

```
from aiogram import types
from bot import dp
    
# simple profanity check
@dp.message_handler()
async def filter_messages(message: types.Message):
    if "bad words" in message.text:
        #profanity detected, remove
        await message.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Пример моего проекта с вынесением самописных модулей.

Структура проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

main.py

```
from aiogram import executor
from misc import dispatcher
import handlers

if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dispatcher, skip_updates=True)
```

misc.py

```
import logging
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from aiogram.contrib.fsm_storage.memory import MemoryStorage
from configuration_handler import Configuration_Handler as config


token = config().getting_data_from_configuration_settings('TelegramToken', 'Api_key')
bot = Bot(token=token)
memory_storage = MemoryStorage()
dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, storage=memory_storage)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
```

handlers/**init**.py

```
from . import general_commands
from . import default_handler
from . import currency
from . import url_shortening
from . import download_youtube
from . import pokemon
from . import gallows
```

handlers/pokemon.py

```
from misc import dispatcher
from misc import bot
from aiogram import types

import requests
import random
import main

@dispatcher.message_handler(commands="pokemon", state="*")
async def what_pokemon_are_you(message: types.Message):
    number = random.randint(1, 500)
    pokemon_list = []
    url = f'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-form/{number}/'
    r = requests.get(url)
    r = r.json()
    pokemon_list.append(r.get('pokemon').get('name'))
    pokemon_list.append(r.get('sprites').get('front_default'))
    await message.answer(f"Поздравляю ты {str(pokemon_list[0]).title()}, ты очень сильный Pokemon!")
    await bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=str(pokemon_list[1]))
```

Архитектура:
При запуске main импортируем:

```
from aiogram import executor
from misc import dispatcher
# Наши команды вынесенные в отдельный модуль
import handlers
```

после чего запускаем `executor.start_polling(dispatcher, skip_updates=True)`
инициализируя `dispatcher`
Поскольку мы импортировали `import handlers` являющийся отдельным модулем, каждый раз когда бот будет получать команды, он будет проверять их в handlers/**init**.py
для этого в pokemon.py мы импортируем `from misc import dispatcher` который и хранит в себе все эти команды

```
@dispatcher.message_handler(commands="pokemon", state="*")
async def what_pokemon_are_you(message: types.Message):
```

При этом мы не должны импортировать наш модуль в файл где определяется `dispatcher = Dispatcher(bot, storage=memory_storage)`
Иначе мы получить ошибку цикличного импорта.
По этому все инициализируется не в main а в misc, откуда уже импортируется в main и наш модуль