# Как отправить сообщение aiogram из другого файл

Tags: python, aiogram

К примеру есть есть файл, в котором лежит функция

*some_file.py*

```py
from bot import send_message

def F():
    if что-то:
        send_message('1')
    else:
        send_message('2')
```

И второй файл с ботом тг

*bot.py*

```py
from aiogram import Bot

TOKEN = 'token'
bot = Bot(token=TOKEN)

async send_message(m):
    await bot.send_message(123, m)
```

Как вызывая функцию из some_file.py все же отправлялось сообщение. Потому что вылезает async ошибка, а делать все функции асинхронными не вариант.

Comment: То есть вы хотите просто запустить функцию, которая лежит в другом файле?

Answer (score 0):

Если импортировать bot из bot.py в some_file.py словим ошибку циклического импорта, при импорте F() из some_file.py в bot.py

Предлагаю такой вариант [Тык](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1309584/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC/1312380#1312380) (в решении)

У тебя будет отдельный модуль в котором можно разбить каждый файл на отдельную команду.
Модуль handlers импортируется в основной файл и тогда aiogramm сам будет искать нужную команду в этом модуле.

Я считаю такое разбиение логики на разные файлы хорошо сказывается на поддержку и читаемость кода.
Если сильно надо, большую логику можно разбивать на под модули внутри модуля handlers